# struct.error reported in pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python program that failed with

```
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a string
```

I tracked down and found the following attempt got stuck:

```
struct.pack('!iiiibc30s', 48, 11718431L, 4190519, 10773240, 1, 'b', u'libmkl_core.dylib\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

I think this is a unicode issue, but not sure why this happen and how to fix this. The python program I used is "pyinstaller", and this happened when I was trying to build a single executable. TThe python version I was using is 2.7, and the system is mountain lion.

Comment: Did you specify libmkl_core.dylib in your spec file? If yes, how?

Comment: No, I didn't explicitly specify the libmkl_core.dylib in my spec file. I went through the pyinstall documents and to be honest, I do not know how except trial-and-error. I appreciate if you could tell me how to do that.

Comment: Can you post your script or at least the part that has the imports. You don't need to add libmkl_core.dylib . Since you mentioned the error location I thought it was because of that file.